# Count how many values are above limit in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with test values of 20 different teststeps from some units (e.g. unit 1..5)
In addition I have 2 columns with lower and upper limit (ll and ul)

```
data <- data.frame(
    ll=round(runif(20,5,15)),
    ul=round(runif(20,80,95)),
    unit1=sample(1:100,20,TRUE),
    unit2=sample(1:100,20,TRUE),
    unit3=sample(1:100,20,TRUE),
    unit4=sample(1:100,20,TRUE),
    unit5=sample(1:100,20,TRUE)
)
```

How do I get a count of values for each row which are below the lower limit (ll) and what count is above the upper limit (ul)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
below <- rowSums(data[,-c(1,2)] < data[,'ll'])  # below
above <- rowSums(data[,-c(1,2)] > data[,'ul'])  # above
DF <- cbind(data, below, above) # altogether
head(DF)
  ll ul unit1 unit2 unit3 unit4 unit5 below above
1 10 82    75    10    24    80    60     0     0
2 13 87    60    20     4    94    31     1     1
3  8 85    58     9    98    94    65     0     2
4 11 95    68    45     5    38    76     1     0
5 11 87    15    79     5    43    67     1     0
6 11 89    33     6    18     1    22     2     0
```

Comment: +1 for the nice direct solution. I've adapted it to `transform` and `within` in my answer, which I both find to be pretty useful functions in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `within()` for this, following the same logic as @Jilber's answer:

```
# First, use set.seed to make your example reproducible
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(
  ll=round(runif(5, 5, 15)),
  ul=round(runif(5, 80, 95)),
  unit1=sample(1:100, 5, TRUE),
  unit2=sample(1:100, 5, TRUE),
  unit3=sample(1:100, 5, TRUE),
  unit4=sample(1:100, 5, TRUE),
  unit5=sample(1:100, 5, TRUE)
)
data
#   ll ul unit1 unit2 unit3 unit4 unit5
# 1  8 93    21    50    94    39    49
# 2  9 94    18    72    22     2    60
# 3 11 90    69   100    66    39    50
# 4 14 89    39    39    13    87    19
# 5  7 81    77    78    27    35    83
```

The `within` function lets you add new columns in a convenient way.

```
within(data, {
  below = rowSums(data[-c(1:2)] < ll)
  above = rowSums(data[-c(1:2)] > ul)
})
#   ll ul unit1 unit2 unit3 unit4 unit5 above below
# 1  8 93    21    50    94    39    49     1     0
# 2  9 94    18    72    22     2    60     0     1
# 3 11 90    69   100    66    39    50     1     0
# 4 14 89    39    39    13    87    19     0     1
# 5  7 81    77    78    27    35    83     1     0
```

Alternatively, you can also use `transform()` to achieve the same output:

```
transform(data, 
          below = rowSums(data[-c(1:2)] < ll), 
          above = rowSums(data[-c(1:2)] > ul))
```

Benchmarking the Jilber's solution and these two on a 2,000,000 row dataset, here are the results:

```
       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
3    jilber            3  33.586    1.000    31.490    1.916
1    within            3  34.493    1.027    32.542    1.584
2 transform            3  33.813    1.007    31.870    1.828
```

I think these two functions hold up pretty well for the convenience they offer!

Comment: thanks this is quite short and it works fine for me.
Also the hint with the set.seed(1) is good

Comment: @user1716533, sure. Just remember that you can set your seed to any value you want.

Comment: +1 for the good implementations using within and transform and also for benchmarking.